# Validate json string against api.model

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I want to post json along with image bytes.
I'm using api.parser to specify expected parameters:

```py
upload_parser = api.parser()
a=True
upload_parser.add_argument('image',
                           location='files',
                           type=FileStorage,
                           required=True)
# json string
upload_parser.add_argument('params', location='form', type='string')
```

How could i validate json string against `api.model`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out simply `api.model.validate()` is enough.

```py
payload = json.loads(request.form['params'])       
my_model.validate(payload)
```